# How to load a big web page partially with UIWebView? like Mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad

My app crashes every time I tried to load a very large web page. However Mobile Safari doesn't crash when I load the same page, it only renders part of it. (Checkerboard pattern is shown for the unrendered region). How can I do the same with UIWebView and manage memory effectively?

Comment: Hey frnd did you found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do anything to fix this. Safari and UIWebView behaves differently

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use WKWebView in iOS 8. It may give you the same power as Safari